# Using 'styled()' MUI System utility with additional props (Typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm working on a new project with MUI System v5. I'm using `styled()` utility here (not styled-components) to style and create simple UI components. The project is in TypeScript. I have a lot of difficulties now because I don't know if and how I can pass props to such components.
For example, I have a component like this:

```
import { styled } from '@mui/system';


const InputField = styled('input')(({ width }) => ({
  width: width
}));
```

and I want to use it in this way:

```
return <InputField width={100}>
```

but it gives me an error:

`Property 'width' does not exist on type '{ theme?: Theme; as?: ElementType<any>; sx?: SxProps<Theme>; } & ClassAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & { ...; }'.ts(2339)`

So my question is: how can I provide additional props for such Material UI components have?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You can add the generic type parameter to the returned function of `styled` like this:

```
type InputProps = {
  width: number
}

const InputField = styled('input')<InputProps>(({ width }) => ({
  width: width
}));
```

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Comment: Perfect answer, thank you!

Comment: What is I have a MUI component in place of 'input' and have custom objects in my MUI theme which have been added via module augmentation

Answer (score 0):

first import in your project:

```
                 import { StandardCSSProperties } from "@mui/system";
```

you can use the type in your interface:

```
                                                     *['nameStyle']*
                 marginBottom?:  StandardCSSProperties['marginBottom'];
```

passing the prop to the function

```
                 function Input({ marginBottom }: props) {
```

finally pass ownership to sx

```
                 sx={{
                    marginBottom: marginBottom || 2,
                    }}
```

You can also in your interface:

```
                    sx?: SxProps;
```

and use on sx:

```
                    sx={sx}
```

version MUi: "@mui/material": "5.10.16",