# MUI v5 (Styled, TypeScript) System props transmission error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, styled-components

I just started learning Material ui and ran into a problem:

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled, Typography } from '@mui/material';

interface DescriptionProps {
  textTitle: string;
  type?: string;
}

const TitleStyled = styled(Typography, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "isSubtitle",
})<{ isSubtitle?: string; }>(({ isSubtitle }) => ({
  fontWeight: 700,
  fontSize: isSubtitle ? '18px' : '24px',
  lineHeight: isSubtitle ? '21px' : '28px',
  letterSpacing: 'inherit'
}))

export const Description = ({
  textTitle,
  type = '',
}: DescriptionProps) => {
  const customTag = type === 'subtitle' ? 'h3' : 'h2';

  return (
    <TitleStyled
      component={customTag}   //  Error
      isSubtitle={type}
    >
      {textTitle}
    </TitleStyled>
  );
};
```

Error :

> TS2322: Type '{ children: string; component: string; isSubtitle: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps & { align?: "right" | "left" | "center" | "inherit" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.   Property 'component' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & SystemProps & { align?: "right" | "left" | "center" | "inherit" | "justify" | undefined; children?: ReactNode; ... 6 more ...; variantMapping?: Partial<...> | undefined; } & CommonProps & Omit<...> & MUIStyledCommonProps<...> & { ...; }'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W7qd2.png)

I tried to add `as typeof Typography`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCEbb.png)

***Update:***
added to config.json:

```
"compilerOptions": {
   "paths": {
      "@mui/system": "@mui/material/node_modules/@mui/system"
   },
```

the application is working, but the error is still highlighted in red

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a type for the `component` prop:

```
const TitleStyled = styled(Typography, {
  shouldForwardProp: (prop) => prop !== "isSubtitle"
})<{ 
  isSubtitle?: string, 
  component: string // <= Add a type for component:
}>(({ isSubtitle }) => ({
...
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69618158/using-styled-mui-utility-with-additional-props-typescript)

Comment: Thanks! It works =) although I think I tried to add the type...